# Order by inside a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view, sql-order-by

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
WHERE u.id IN 
((SELECT l.id FROM location l WHERE l.id = ?id ORDER BY l.idLocation DESC ))
```

What I want to do is make this Order By works. But It's not possible to have a order by inside a view. How can I do this order by if not inside a view?

**SQL Response:**

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Do you mean a sub-query? I don't see a view here.

Comment: I don't see how making the `ORDER BY` work would ever have any effect on the output. Can you give us an example of what output you are getting now, and how you wish it was different? Inside an `IN` statement the `ORDER BY` is unlikely to matter even if it "worked," so you're going to get some confused answers.

Comment: +1 @ChrisCunningham - OP, it's not clear from the original query what order you want the results in, since you're merely checking whether u.id is IN the subselect's results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Only the *outermost* ORDER BY matters.

So `SELECT * FROM MyView ORDER By Whatever` is the **only** way.

Any intermediate ordering (whether ORDER BY or coincidental, or part of the lan) is *ignored*

Comment: Thanks. Poor of me, i'm gonna have to find another way to do it then.

Comment: @pringlesinn - do **what**? - that's the great mystery at the moment.

Comment: If I have an table of articles and I need to display them ordered A-Z or Z-A but I also want to select 100 at a time. ORDER BY outside orders only the selected 100. How to do that for all?

Comment: This is not correct. Many situations benefit from an inner `ORDER BY`. Pagination queries are a common example. Ordering within the subquery gets rows ordered at a table-scope. The outermost ORDER BY orders only within the scope of the final results.

Answer (score 8):

There's two issues here.

1 - **Your `ORDER BY` is pointless.**  When you use an `IN` subquery, `ORDER` is irrelevant.

2 - The `ORDER BY` for a view should be in the calling query, not in the view itself.

Answer (score 2):

I share the opinion with the previous answers that it is not generally a good idea to do an `order by` in a sub-query.  However, I have found that it is sometimes very useful to do just that.  I assume the sample query in ***pringlesinn***'s question is a simple example of a more complex requirement.  You can do an `order by` in a sub-query this way:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
WHERE exists
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.idLocation DESC) FROM location l WHERE u.id = l.id and l.id = ?id)
```

You'll notice however that the WHERE clause no longer uses an 'IN' operator.  Instead you have to use 'EXISTS' and do a correlated sub-query.  Or you could do something like this:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u inner join 
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.idLocation DESC) as rowid, l.id 
    FROM location l 
    WHERE l.id = ?id
  ) as z on z.id = u.id
```

Best Wishes,
James

Comment: As **gbn** mentioned, the `order by` is ignored in the inner query.  I checked execution plan of these two code snippets and the `order by` did appear to be eliminated.  I do recall however that using the above approach in a much more complex situation was the best way to achieve the task.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

If you want to add an `ORDER BY` to the view you can add a `TOP(100) PERCENT` to your view and then you can use it.

http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2007/01/sql-server-order-view.html